# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Callback was already called (Loopback remote method)

Tags: node.js, async-await, loopbackjs, es6-promise

I'm getting an error that says

```
(node:27301) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Callback was already called.
```

From what I understand about rejecting promises in await's and per the Mozilla description:

> If the Promise is rejected, the await expression throws the rejected value.

I reject the error in the callback that's wrapped around my Promise like so:

```
Airport.nearbyAirports = async (location, cb) => {
  let airports
  try {
    airports = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Airport.find({
        // code
      }, (err, results) => {
        if (err)
          reject(err) // Reject here
        else
          resolve(results)
      })
    })
  } catch (err) { // Catch here
    cb(err, null)
    return
  }
  if (!airports.empty)
    cb(null, airports)
  }
```

My question is

1. Why does it still consider my promise rejection unhandled? I thought the `catch` statement should silent this error.
2. Why does it consider my callback already called? I have a `return` statement in my `catch`, so both should never be called.

Comment: is it by chance possible that the case where you resolve and reject that you don't have `results` or an `err`?

Comment: `err` is provided by the 3rd party API, and when I tested it I always got `results`. My function returns correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was actually my framework (LoopbackJS), not my function. Apparently at the time of writing this, using promises are not supported:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-promises.html#setup

Meaning I can't even use `await` in my function because the remote method wraps my function somewhere else, so `async` would always be unhandled. I ended up going back to a Promise-based implementation of the inner code:

```
Airport.nearbyAirports = (location, cb) => {
const settings = Airport.dataSource.settings
const db = DB(settings)
let airports
NAME_OF_QUERY().then((res) => {
  cb(null, res)
}).catch((err) => {
  cb(err, null)
})
```

Comment: Relevant github issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/418

Answer (score 2):

If `Airport.find()` throws an exception, then execution will jump to your `catch` block and your `Promise` will never be resolved or rejected. Perhaps you need to wrap it in its own `try/catch`:

```
Airport.nearbyAirports = async (location, cb) => {
  let airports
  try {
    airports = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        Airport.find({
          // code
        }, (err, results) => {
          if (err)
            reject(err) // Reject here
          else
            resolve(results)
        })
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err) // Reject here too
        cb(err, null)
      }
    })
  } catch (err) { // Catch here
    cb(err, null)
    return
  }
  if (!airports.empty)
    cb(null, airports)
  }
```

Comment: But then this doesn't use `await` anymore, which is what I originally intended. How could I make it so it does?

Comment: Yes it does. I was only showing a new `try/catch` inside the scope of the `Promise`. I've updated my code to include all of your code as well to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As [said here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3400#issuecomment-356817049), loopback 3 support this by allowing you to use a simple return.

This :

```
Entry.findFooById = async (id, cb) => {
  const result = await Entry.findById(id);
  return result;
};
```

...Is equivalent to :

```
Entry.findFooById = (id, cb) => {
  Entry.findById(id)
    .then(result => cb(null, result))
    .catch(cb);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

We use Loopback 2.31.0 and it also supports simple return for async functions used for remote methods. If you put a break-point somewhere in your remote method and jump one level above it in the call-stack you will see how it is implemented in loopback itself ([shared-method.js](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting/blob/master/lib/shared-method.js#L268)):

```
  // invoke
  try {
    var retval = method.apply(scope, formattedArgs);
    if (retval && typeof retval.then === 'function') {
      return retval.then(
        function(args) {
          if (returns.length === 1) args = [args];
          var result = SharedMethod.toResult(returns, args);
          debug('- %s - promise result %j', sharedMethod.name, result);
          cb(null, result);
        },
        cb // error handler
      );
    }
    return retval;
  } catch (err) {
    debug('error caught during the invocation of %s', this.name);
    return cb(err);
  }
};
```

What it does here - it calls your function and if it is an async function - it will return a promise (`retval.then === 'function'` will be `true`). In this case loopback will handle your result correctly, as a promise. It also do the error check for you, so you no longer try/catch blocks in your code anymore.

So, in your own code you just need to use it like below:

```
Airport.nearbyAirports = async (location) => {
    let airports = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Airport.find({
            // code
        }, (err, results) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err) // Reject here
            else
                resolve(results)
        })
    });

    if (!airports.empty)
        return airports;
    }
    else  {
        return {}; // not sure what you would like to return here as it wan not handled in your sample...
    }
}
```

Note, you do not need to use callback (cb) at all here.